# How to write this Linq Query in a better way to return the sum

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I have one LINQ query. In that I need to do some calculations. Everything is fine except when null value found in the either one condition then simply it returns null for the whole condition. Can anyone tell me how can i return the some value even there is a null value found in the condition.

**Code**

```
var model = 
   (from q in db.Porders
    select new porders()
    {
        Id = q.Id,
        DetCount = (from amtdet in db.PoDetails 
                    where amtdet.PoId == q.Id 
                    select amtdet.Id).Count(),
        Amount = (from amtpord in db.Porders 
                  where amtpord.Id == q.Id 
                  select amtpord.Freight + amtpord.Misc - amtpord.Discount
                 ).FirstOrDefault() +
                  (from amtdet in db.PoDetails 
                   where amtdet.PoId == q.Id 
                   select amtdet.Copies * amtdet.EstUnitPrice
                  ).Sum()
     }).ToList();
```

Comment: you `select` is okay, but you need to use the `Linq join` and `group by` Porders -> Porders -> PoDetails by `DefaultOrEmpty` and get for Count and then Sum Amount.

Comment: Have you got navigation properties like `Porder.Details`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `DefaultIfEmpty()` method will be the solution here

```
var model =
    from q in db.Porders
    select new porders()
    {
        DetCount = 
            db.PoDetails.Count(amtdet => amtdet.PoId == q.Id),
        Amount = 
            (from amtpord in db.Porders
            where amtpord.Id == q.Id
            select amtpord.Freight + amtpord.Misc - amtpord.Discount)
            .DefaultIfEmpty().First()
            +
            (from amtdet in db.PoDetails
            where amtdet.PoId == q.Id
            select amtdet.Copies * amtdet.EstUnitPrice)
            .DefaultIfEmpty().Sum()
    }
```

Comment: => Resulting the same null value after using DefaultIfEmpty().

Comment: Which of the subqueries is returning `null`?

Answer (score 0):

Try applying coalescing `column ?? 0` operator on nullable columns or on the result of the `FirstOrDefault` (for the case that condition is not met). Linq to entities will turn this operator into SQL:

`CASE WHEN Column IS NOT NULL THEN Column ELSE 0 END`

It will look like:

```
var model = 
   (from q in db.Porders
    select new porders()
    {
        Id = q.Id,
        Amount = (from amtpord in db.Porders 
                  where amtpord.Id == q.Id 
                  select amtpord.Freight ?? 0 + amtpord.Misc ?? 0 - amtpord.Discount ?? 0
                 ).FirstOrDefault() ?? 0 +
                  (from amtdet in db.PoDetails 
                   where amtdet.PoId == q.Id 
                   select amtdet.Copies ?? 0 * amtdet.EstUnitPrice ?? 0
                  ).Sum() ?? 0
     }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me first assume that there is a navigation property `Porder.Details`. Next, why do you select the same `Porder` in a sub query? It seems to me that your query can be simplified as

```
from q in db.Porders
    select new porders()
    {
        Id = q.Id,
        DetCount = q.Details.Count(),
        Amount = q.Freight + q.Misc - q.Discount
               + q.PoDetails.Select( d => d.Copies * d.EstUnitPrice)
                  .DefaultIfEmpty().Sum()
    }
```

If there isn't such a navigation property it is highly recommended to create one. If you can't or don't want to do that for whatever reason, you should group join the detail records in the main query (`db.Porders.GroupJoin(db.PoDetails...)`).

If the null values are caused by `Freight`, `Misc` or `Discount` to be nullable, use `??` operator: `q.Freight ?? 0`.